# Rake Aborted Error - Cant find bundler - Can't install bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello i just made a scaffold. Then tried to run rake db:migrate. Tried to install bundler but can't. Can anyone help?

```
Joey@JOEY-PC ~/desktop/safsy (master)
$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
c:/Users/Joey/desktop/safsy/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
c:/Users/Joey/desktop/safsy/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
c:/Users/Joey/desktop/safsy/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Joey@JOEY-PC ~/desktop/safsy (master)
$ gem install bundler
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=
SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.
8.gz)


Joey@JOEY-PC ~/desktop/safsy (master)
$ gem install bundler
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=
SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.
8.gz)
```

Comment: Have you tried running `gem install bundler`?

Comment: Yes i did. Its in the code i posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it seems that's exactly your problem:

https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88